# Why "point" rule matches more then one number?

Tags: antlr4

I try to write my first parser with ANTLR4. One of the rules I use in a already bigger grammerfile is supposed to match 2 numbers as a 2D-point. Here a cut down example of the grammer:

```
grammar example;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
INT: [0-9]+;
FLOAT: [0-9]*'.'?[0-9]+ ;
IDSTRING:  [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*;
NUMBER: (INT | FLOAT) ;

id: IDSTRING;
num: NUMBER;
sem: ';' ;
point: num num;

macro: 'MACRO' id macroprops* 'END ' id;
macroprops:  macroorigin ;
macroorigin: 'ORIGIN' point sem;
```

When I know enter a basic example like this:

```
antlr4 example.g4 -o example/ 
cd example 
javac *.java 
echo -e "MACRO m_1\n  ORIGIN 7 2.0  ;\nEND m_1" | grun example macro -tree
```

the first `num` in point matches both numbers and it throws an error, that any integer (here 0) is not a number:

```
line 3:9 mismatched input '0' expecting NUMBER
(macro MACRO (id m_1) (macroprops (macroorigin ORIGIN (point (num 0 0) (num <missing NUMBER>)) (sem ;))) END  (id m_1))
```

I tried the definition of `NUMBER` and `point` for some different ways, but I suppose it should work like this. I dont't even understandhow `num` can match two token. Anybody can help?

Comment: Dump the token stream to verify that the lexer is doing what you expect.

Comment: `echo -e "MACRO m_1\n  ORIGIN 7 2.0  ;\nEND m_1" | grun example macro -tree` gives me as one result `[@6,19:21='2.0',<FLOAT>,2:9]`. Seems like the the matches `FLOAT` instead of `NUMBER`...

Comment: A consequence of your grammar being 'upside-down': ANTLR evaluates rules 'top-down'/longest-match wins. The `FLOAT` rule is listed above, so a float token is emitted, rather than a `NUMBER` token. The error indicates that the `point` rule failed to match a `num`, given that the encountered token was a `FLOAT`.

Comment: But why does the parser then push both numbers into the `NUM` rule?

Comment: That is not what the error message is saying. Read it as a hint that there was a problem in matching something to an expected `num` in the `point` rule. That is why dumping the token stream is so helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems as ANTLR4 matches the TOKENS as the order of them given in the grammer. Adding `fragment` to `INT` and `FLOAT` fixed the problem, as `NUMBER` is the only TOKEN matching the number definition allowing both floats and ints then.

```
grammar example2;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);

NUMBER: (INT | FLOAT) ;
fragment INT: [0-9]+;
fragment FLOAT: [0-9]*'.'?[0-9]+ ;
IDSTRING:  [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]*;

id: IDSTRING;
num: NUMBER;
sem: ';' ;
point: num num;

macro: 'MACRO' id macroprops* 'END ' id;
macroprops:  macroorigin ;
macroorigin: 'ORIGIN' point sem;
```

Thank you very much for pointing out to watch the token stream. But I still don't understand why it then matches both numbers to the `num` rule in the original question.

EDIT: Another mistake was, as mentioned by GRosenberg to just define the grammer elements in the rigth order, so `NUMBER` has a higher priority then it`s subrules.